# Derived class cannot access base class's protected member variable without base class's qualifier

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Object>
class Vector {
class const_iterator {
public:
    const Object& operator * () const       { return retrieve(); }

    const_iterator& operator ++ () {
        ++current;
        return *this;
    }

    const_iterator operator ++ (int) {
        auto old { *this};
        ++( *this);
        return old;
    }

    bool operator == (const const_iterator& rhs) const      { return current == rhs.current; }
    bool operator != (const const_iterator& rhs) const      { return !( *this == rhs); }

protected:
    Object* current;
    const Vector<Object>* theVect;

    Object& retrieve() const {
        assertIsValid();
        return *current;
    }

    const_iterator(const Vector<Object>& vect, Object* p)
        : theVect { &vect}, current {p}         { }

    void assertIsValid() const {
        if (theVect == nullptr || current == nullptr) {
            // throw IteratorOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    friend class Vector<Object>;
};

class iterator : public const_iterator {
public:
    const Object& operator * () const       { return const_iterator::operator * (); }
    Object& operator * ()       { return const_cast<Object& > (std::as_const( *this).operator * () ); }

    iterator& operator ++ () {
```

Why current here cannot be accessed without "const_iterator::"? 
But "++const_iterator::current" is OK. 
What's going on here? Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much!!!

```
        ++current;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator ++ (int) {
        auto old { *this};
        ++ ( *this);
        return old;
    }

protected:
    iterator(const Vector<Object>& vect, Object* p) 
      : const_iterator(vect, p)       { }

    friend class Vector<Object>;
};
};
```

Comment: Please dont add garbage to your post just to get through the editor conditions.. Explain the issue.

Comment: Maybe your class hierarchy is backwards? Perhaps if you make the base class the one that's capable of writing, and derive a class from it that isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a result of C++'s template name-lookup rules. You could also use `this->` instead of the base class qualifier. Basically, in order to make a name lookup depend on a template argument, you have to use that template argument (even if indirectly through a `typedef` or `using`) as part of the name. And note that MSVC still does not enforce this by default, you have to use the `/permissive-` flag to get this behavior with MSVC.